# Talend - tXMLMap to tUnite to Snowflake table

Tags: xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, talend

I am trying to read an XML and load various parts of the XML to their appropriate Snowflake tables.

```
tFileInputXML -> tXMLMap -> tUnite -> tDBRow
```

However, Talend is not allowing 3 outputs from tXMLMap to be connected with tUnite. Only one output could be connected with tUnite.

I have 3 outputs from tXMLMap that needs to be combined to a single Snowflake table. What option can I look into to achieve this? Please help.

Comment: As I sort of show in your other question you should not loop across the three sub object (electrical,mechanical, chemical) you should loop on the deptinfo and then do a single mapping of those values. Given the three sub objects are really just the same thing, but with the "type" in an xml label instead of a value, you might have to do some extrea lifting. But really you trying to "combind" then is sort feel like the wrong way to map them.

Comment: Thanks, Simeon ! The three sub objects need to be loaded the same Table A with an additional column denoting what each sub object denote. Type column in Table A would be defaulted to Electrical, Chemical or Mechanical based on which flow the data comes from.

Comment: Yes, but unless your data is different to how you described it in your other question. The three sub-objects are the same shape, so you don't need to loop across them as different sub-objects to map, they are really the same shape, so you can loop at the higher only level, thus end up with one set of objects, so you don't have to join them together. This is what the SQL I gave you does.